# Python to Excel basics using xlwings

Tags: xlwings

I am new to xlwings and only have a basic knowledge of Python, I use excel for club statistics and  graphs and can see how Python will help speed up these tasks. I am however, struggling with the basics of the Python to Excel process. "Instantiate" a workbook for example, Is there a primer for a dunce like me?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got xlwings installed correctly, you should be able to use the xlwings [command line client](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/command_line.html) to create the quickstart workbook like so:

```
xlwings quickstart myproject
```

Once you've done that, working through the [quickstart tutorial](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) should get you started interacting with excel using a python script.